# Is asking for a resource on topic?

Tags: discussion

I haven't been able to find a Wheel of time FAQ up to date to Towers of Midnight on any of the various mirrors.

Is asking for a faq resource on topic?

Here's the [dragonmount](http://wotfaq.dragonmount.com/) version of the FAQ which is complete up to Knife of Dreams.
Then theres the [steelypips](http://www.steelypips.org/wotfaq/0_admin/0.01_intro.html) version (when it used to be managed by Leigh Butler), which is complete up to Crossroads of Twilight.

Since the dragonmount version we've had The Gathering storm and Towers of Midnight where at least a few prophecies / dreams from earlier books have been fulfilled, i wonder if there is a version of the faq that includes information from these books whilst preparing for A Memory of Light.

Comment: You might need to tell us what the FAQ would do...why would a novel have an FAQ?

Comment: See edit. And because a 13 book long sequence has lots of questions.

Comment: @Pureferret - heh. As someone who grew up on usenet, I find "NOT having a FAQ on any given topic" to be strange, NOT "needing one for a random topic" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it could be. You would have to avoid asking a question whose answers can only be opinions. So don't ask *What is the best WoT FAQ?*, unless you want the question closed immediately.

Instead, ask a question that can have a single, objective answer. Something like *Does an up-to-date WoT FAQ exist?*, or *What is the most up-to-date WoT FAQ?* If all you want is info on prophecies/dreams, incorporate them into your question -- perhaps *What is the most up-to-date WoT FAQ for prophecies and dreams?* Just explain your criteria in the body of your post.

Oh, and spell out *WoT* in your question -- I didn't because I'm lazy.